# How to deal with CursorAdapter and switching Contacts API?

Tags: android, cursor, adapter, android-contacts

Does anyone tried to use `CursorAdapter` with old and new api?

Do you have some code examples of such solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone tried to use ContactAdapter with old and new api?

There is no `ContactAdapter` class in the Android SDK, so I am uncertain what you are referring to here.

> Do you have some code examples of such solutions?

[Here is an example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) that shows using conditional class loading to populate a `SimpleCursorAdapter` based for either the old or new API depending on the version of Android that you are running.